# How to deactivate/remove https on localhost project from online

Tags: https, local-installation

I'm working on a messy customer project.
To debug it, I would like to work on it on localhost.
I'm using Wampserver.

This is what I did :

1 - I made  a virtualhost

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName devfoo.pro
    DocumentRoot "c:/path/to/project/src/www"
    <Directory  "c:/path/to/project/src/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2 - I renamed the file `.htaccess` to `_.htaccess`

At that point when I run the page, there is still a redirection from `http://devfoo.pro` to `https://devfoo.pro`.

Notice : If I rename the plugin `really-simple-ssl` to `_really-simple-ssl`, the page redirect to the online website.

So... how can I import a WordPress project on localhost and deactivate the https protocol properly ? (Keeping the https on localhost is so messy! I never manage to simulate https on a local server with or without documentation, tutorials etc... )

Comment: you are looking for the wrong solution. development enviroment should match that of production as much as possible. Using a different protocol sounds like the wrong way to go. If the certificate can not be utilized on your PC, ask your client to create a development enviroment for you on his servers.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this experience with chrome and firefox, they switch http to https and did not find a way to overcome it, so i used internet explorer in that windows machine.
I don't think you can have ssl on localhost or an ip address, i guess you know it as you used devfoo.pro. SSL certificate could be generated only for fully qualified domain names.

So, you will need to **buy** a certificate to have things working, out of the box. **Easy and "secure"**.
Or you can self sign one for your self, following a tutorial :-). **Might be difficult** and you will need to accept it in your browser or os.
Or better (at least for me), use this [website](http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/). It will self sign a certificate for a provided domain.

Answer (score 0):

to remove `https` on an install, you can do a find and replace on the local database, I found [wpcli is the easiest way](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/):

```
wp search-replace 'https://example.com' 'http://example.com'
wp search-replace 'https://www.example.com' 'http://www.example.com'
```

you can also do a find+replace with a normal `.sql`. be mindful for serialized strings in the _options table, they often break, but if you know it's broken and why it's not hard to fix.

beyond that:

- look for plugins like "force https" and make sure they're removed
- look in wp-config.php and make sure there's no hard coded HTTPS rule in there (sometimes force_ssl, sometimes, site_url, etc.)
- the .htaccess renaming was a good move, but all that needs to be taken out of there is any `http`->`https` rule.

Comment: there are two big holes on this scheme. 1. The assumption that search & replace on the DB will work, and that there is no hardcoded url in the code. 2 browsers have different security models for https, so your ability to debug some of the possibly JS and CSS problems will be reduced.